# How to install SmartCam on Linux?

Tags: software-installation

how to install Smartcam on Ubuntu? In extracted *.tar.gz i type `./configure`:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for intltool >= 0.40.0... 0.51.0 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.30.0
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for GTHREAD... yes
checking for GTK... yes
checking for DBUS... yes
checking for GCONF... yes
checking for hci_open_dev in -lbluetooth... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking jpeglib.h usability... no
checking jpeglib.h presence... no
checking for jpeglib.h... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating data/Makefile
config.status: creating data/smartcam.desktop.in
config.status: creating data/icons/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/16x16/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/22x22/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/24x24/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/32x32/Makefile
config.status: creating data/icons/48x48/Makefile
config.status: creating data/phone_installs/Makefile
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing po/stamp-it commands
```

Then I type `make`:

```
make all-recursive
make [1]: Enter the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0'
Making all in src
make [2]: Enter the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0/src'
make all-am
make [3]: Enter the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0/src'
g ++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I .. -DPACKAGE_DATADIR = \ "/ usr / local / share / smartcam \" -DDATADIR = \ "/ usr / local / share \" -pthread -I / usr / include / gtk-2.0 -I / usr / lib /x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I / usr / include / gtk-2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / gtk-2.0 / include -I / usr / include / pango-1.0 -I / usr / include / atk-1.0 -I / usr / include / gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I / usr / include / libmount -I / usr / include / blkid -I / usr / include / pango-1.0 -I / usr / include / fribidi -I / usr / include / cairo -I / usr / include / pixman-1 -I / usr / include / harfbuzz -I / usr / include / glib-2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64 -linux-gnu / glib-2.0 / include -I / usr / include / uuid -I / usr / include / freetype2 -I / usr / include / libpng16 -pthread -I / usr / include / glib-2.0 -I / usr /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I / usr / include / dbus-1.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / dbus-1.0 / include -I / usr / include / glib -2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / glib-2.0 / include -pthread -I / usr / include / gconf / 2 -I / usr / include / dbus-1.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64 -linux-gnu / dbus-1.0 / include -I / usr / include / libmount -I / usr / include / blkid -I / usr / include / glib-2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / glib-2.0 / include -g -O2 -MT smartcam-SmartEngine.o -MD -MP -MF .deps / smartcam-SmartEngine.Tpo -c -o smartcam-SmartEngine.o `test - f 'SmartEngine.cpp' || echo './'`SmartEngine.cpp
In file included from SmartEngine.cpp: 36:
JpegHandler.h: 26: 10: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
   26 | #include "jpeglib.h"
      | ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make [3]: *** [Makefile: 307: smartcam-SmartEngine.o] Error 1
make [3]: Leave the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0/src'
make [2]: *** [Makefile: 205: all] Error 2
make [2]: Exit the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0/src'
make [1]: *** [Makefile: 245: all-recursive] Error 1
make [1]: Leave the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0'
make: *** [Makefile: 184: all] Error 2
```

First error. I type `sudo make install`:

```
Making install in src
make [1]: Enter the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0/src'
make install-am
make [2]: Enter the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0/src'
g ++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I .. -DPACKAGE_DATADIR = \ "/ usr / local / share / smartcam \" -DDATADIR = \ "/ usr / local / share \" -pthread -I / usr / include / gtk-2.0 -I / usr / lib /x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I / usr / include / gtk-2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / gtk-2.0 / include -I / usr / include / pango-1.0 -I / usr / include / atk-1.0 -I / usr / include / gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I / usr / include / libmount -I / usr / include / blkid -I / usr / include / pango-1.0 -I / usr / include / fribidi -I / usr / include / cairo -I / usr / include / pixman-1 -I / usr / include / harfbuzz -I / usr / include / glib-2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64 -linux-gnu / glib-2.0 / include -I / usr / include / uuid -I / usr / include / freetype2 -I / usr / include / libpng16 -pthread -I / usr / include / glib-2.0 -I / usr /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I / usr / include / dbus-1.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / dbus-1.0 / include -I / usr / include / glib -2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / glib-2.0 / include -pthread -I / usr / include / gconf / 2 -I / usr / include / dbus-1.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64 -linux-gnu / dbus-1.0 / include -I / usr / include / libmount -I / usr / include / blkid -I / usr / include / glib-2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / glib-2.0 / include -g -O2 -MT smartcam-SmartEngine.o -MD -MP -MF .deps / smartcam-SmartEngine.Tpo -c -o smartcam-SmartEngine.o `test - f 'SmartEngine.cpp' || echo './'`SmartEngine.cpp
In file included from SmartEngine.cpp: 36:
JpegHandler.h: 26: 10: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
   26 | #include "jpeglib.h"
      | ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make [2]: *** [Makefile: 307: smartcam-SmartEngine.o] Error 1
make [2]: Exit the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0/src'
make [1]: *** [Makefile: 458: install] Error 2
make [1]: Leave the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0/src'
make: *** [Makefile: 245: install-recursive] Error 1
```

And I can't... please help!!!

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing that `jpeglib.h` is not installed.

You can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, not working :(. I type `make` and error is again:

```
make all-recursive
```

make [1]: Enter the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0'
Making all in src
make [2]: Enter the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0/src'
make all-am
make [3]: Enter the directory '/home/krystian/Pobrane/smartcam-1.4.0/src'
g ++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I .. -DPACKAGE_DATADIR = \ "/ usr / local / share / smartcam " -DDATADIR = \ "/ usr / local / share " -pthread -I / usr / include / gtk-2.0 -I / usr / lib /x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I / usr / include / gtk-2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / gtk-2.0 / include -I / usr / include / pango-1.0 -I / usr / include / atk-1.0 -I / usr / include / gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I / usr / include / libmount -I / usr / include / blkid -I / usr / include / pango-1.0 -I / usr / include / fribidi -I / usr / include / cairo -I / usr / include / pixman-1 -I / usr / include / harfbuzz -I / usr / include / glib-2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64 -linux-gnu / glib-2.0 / include -I / usr / include / uuid -I / usr / include / freetype2 -I / usr / include / libpng16 -pthread -I / usr / include / glib-2.0 -I / usr /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I / usr / include / dbus-1.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / dbus-1.0 / include -I / usr / include / glib -2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / glib-2.0 / include -pthread -I / usr / include / gconf / 2 -I / usr / include / dbus-1.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64 -linux-gnu / dbus-1.0 / include -I / usr / include / libmount -I / usr / include / blkid -I / usr / include / glib-2.0 -I / usr / lib / x86_64-linux-gnu / glib-2.0 / include -g -O2 -MT smartcam-SmartEngine.o -MD -MP -MF .deps / smartcam-SmartEngine.Tpo -c -o smartcam-SmartEngine.o `test - f 'SmartEngine.cpp' || echo './'`SmartEngine.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkobject.h:37,
from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:36,
from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkcontainer.h:35,
from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkbin.h:35,
from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:36,
from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:35,
from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:32,
from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
from SmartEngine.h: 25,
from SmartEngine.cpp: 33:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktypeutils.h:236:64: warning: 'GTypeDebugFlags' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
236 | void gtk_type_init (GTypeDebugFlags debug_flags);
| ^
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:24,
from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
from /usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-glib.h:27,
from /usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-glib-lowlevel.h:27,
from SmartEngine.cpp: 30:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:685:3: note: declared here
685 | } GTypeDebugFlags GLIB_DEPRECATED_TYPE_IN_2_36;
| ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolitem.h:31,
from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktoolbutton.h:30,
from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkmenutoolbutton.h:30,
from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:126,
from SmartEngine.h: 25,
from SmartEngine.cpp: 33:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtktooltips.h:73:12: warning: 'GTimeVal' is deprecated: Use 'GDateTime' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
73 | GTimeVal last_popdown;
| ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
from /usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-glib.h:27,
from /usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-glib-lowlevel.h:27,
from SmartEngine.cpp: 30:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:545:26: note: declared here
545 | typedef struct _GTimeVal GTimeVal GLIB_DEPRECATED_TYPE_IN_2_62_FOR (GDateTime);
| ^ ~~~~~~~
SmartEngine.cpp: In member function 'int CSmartEngine :: StartCommThread ()':
SmartEngine.cpp: 286: 68: warning: ´ GThread * g_thread_create (GThreadFunc, gpointer, gboolean, GError **) ’is deprecated: Use 'g_thread_new' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
286 | commThread = g_thread_create (CommThreadProc, NULL, TRUE, & error);
| ^
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:111,
from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
from /usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-glib.h:27,
from /usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-glib-lowlevel.h:27,
from SmartEngine.cpp: 30:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/deprecated/gthread.h:100:10: note: declared here
100 | GThread * g_thread_create (GThreadFunc func,
| ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
SmartEngine.cpp: 286: 68: warning: '

And it's not working... `sudo make install` is not working too